# Implementing QuadTree Terrain on a Planet (Geomipmapping)

Tags: c++, opengl, terrain, quadtree

I have a QuadTree which can be subdivided by placing objects in the nodes. I also have a planet made in OpenGL in the form of a Quad Sphere. The problem is i don't know how to put them together. How does a QuadTree store information about the Planet? Do i store vertices in the leaf Quad Tree nodes? And if so how do i split the vertex data into 4 sets without ruining the texturing and normals. If this is the case do i use Indices instead?

So my question in short really is:

How do i store my vertices data in a quad tree so that i can split the terrain on the planet up so that the planet will become higher detail at closer range. I assume this is done by using a Camera as the object that splits the nodes.

I've read many articles and most of them fail to cover this. The Quadtree is one of the most important things for my application as it will allow me to render many planets at the same time while still being able to get good definition at land. A pretty picture of my planet and it's HD sun:
 [image: A pretty picture of my planet and it's HD sun!]

A video of the planet can also be found [Here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxU-0LaBDlY)

I've managed to implement a simple quad tree on a flat plane but i keep getting massive holes as i think i'm getting the positions wrong. It's the last post on here - http://www.gamedev.net/topic/637956-opengl-procedural-planet-generation-quadtrees-and-geomipmapping/ and you can get the src there too. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an algorithm like [ROAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROAM) (Real-time Optimally Adapting Mesh) to be able to increase or decrease the accuracy of your model based on the distance of the camera. The algorithm will make use of your quadtree then.

Check out this series on gamasutra on how to render a [Real-time Procedural Universe](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3042/a_realtime_procedural_universe_.php).

**Edit:** the reason why you would use a quadtree with these methods is to minimize the number of vertices in areas where detail is not needed (flat terrain for example). The quadtree definition on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) is pretty good, you should use that as a starting point. The goal is to create child nodes to your quadtree where you have changes in your "height" (you could generate the sides of your cube using an heightmap) until you reach a predefined depth.  Maybe, as a first pass, you should try avoiding the quadtree and use a simple grid. When you get that working, you "optimize" your process by adding the quadtree.

Comment: A real time procedural universe is my end goal. However, after looking around the internet it seems the way to achieve ROAM would be to use an adaptive Quad Tree due to the fact my terrain is made from a cube. An example of where i got this information: http://acko.net/blog/making-worlds-1-of-spheres-and-cubes/ I'd like to deal with the problems one step at a time. As if i can't even figure out how to put my data in the quad tree i likely won't be able to implement ROAM...

Comment: Can you direct me to anything that will actually explain how to store data in a QuadTree and how to split the data when splitting the Quad Tree.

Comment: After looking around about ROAM it seems that it needs data structures such as a Binary Triangle Tree. Which will still leave me at the same problem. As well as the fact that all heights are generated in the shader. If i can just split the terrain into more vertices the shader will compute the heights i believe and therefore create higher definition and smoothed edges.

Comment: I've also just come across the Diamond Square algorithm. Which do you think will be best for a planet like this?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a bit busy at the moment, I'll try to update my answer later, but the best advice I could give you would be to start by having a fixed grid corresponding to mip level `n` and THEN optimize by changing your triangle representation

Comment: What i'm really after is how to actually fill the quad tree and split the vertices. I think i can work the rest out from the article.

Comment: For example - How could i change this to make it usable in terrain - https://github.com/veeableful/Adaptive_Quadtree_Minimal

Comment: I'll check your link later, but read Admiral's answer: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/410611-creating-a-quadtree-with-a-height-map-generated-terrain/

Comment: So each node will have a 'mesh' equivelant to a certain amount of triangles which stays the same throughout. Therefore if i subdivide it therefore increases the triangle amount in that area by 4x? How does one actually subdivide an array of vertices.

Comment: Another question... Do i start off highest detail on my cube and then put it in the Quadtree or do i start off with a low detail on my cube to increase loading time and generate the vertices at each subdivision.

Answer (score 0):

To understand how quadtree and terrain data works together to achieve LOD based rendering
Read [this paper](http://www.stereofx.org/papers/TERRAIN.PDF). Easy to understand with illustrative examples.

I did once implement a LOD on a sphere. The idea is to start with a simple Dipyramid, the upper pyramid representing the northern sphere and the lower one representing the southern sphere. The the bases of the pyramids align with equator, the tips are on poles.
Then you subdivide each triangle into 4 smaller ones **as much as you want** by connecting the midpoints of the edges of the triangle.
The **as much as you want** is based on your needs, distance to camera and object placements could be your triggers for subdivision